# Precal Optimisation Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, optimization

[image]

This is a homework problem I'm struggling with. I've made a linear equation $y = a(x-1) + 2$, and I've figured out that $a$ could be $-2/(x-1)$, but afterwards, I'm stuck as to how to approach b) and c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a, you have two points on the line, $(x,0)$ and $(1,2)$.  You have two uses of $x$ in your work, the point where the line hits the axis and the coordinate you use for the line, which leads to confusion.  If we make the point where the line hits the axis $(b,0)$ the line is then $y=\frac{-2(x-1)}{b-1}+2$.  Now find the intersection with the $y$ axis by plugging in $x=0$ and compute the length of the hypotenuse.